# TypeError in Fibonacci function

Tags: python

```
def Fastfib(n, memo):
    global numcalls
    numcalls += n
    print ('fib called with', n)
    if not n in memo:
        memo[n] = fastFib(n-1, memo) + fastFib(n-2, memo)   
    return memo(n)
numcalls = 0
n = 6
res = Fastfib(n)
print ('fib of', n, '*', res, 'numcalls *', numcalls,)
```

When I run the code it brings back this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\fib1.py", line 10, in <module>
TypeError: Fastfib() missing 1 required positional argument: 'memo'
```

Comment: you don't pass enough args and you also mix lower and upper case f's, `fastFib != FastFib` also `memo(n)` is not going to work. Your algorithm is also incorrect

Answer (score 0):

```
def Fastfib(n, memo):
    global numcalls   
    # base case     
    if n < 2:
        return n
    numcalls += n
    print ('fib called with {}'.format(n))
    if n not in memo:
        # FastFib not fastFib
        memo[n] = Fastfib(n-1, memo) + Fastfib(n-2, memo)
    return memo[n] # not memo(n)

res = Fastfib(n,{}) # call with two args

In [5]: print ('fib of {}  is {}.\nRecursive calls {}'.format(n, res, numcalls))
fib of 100  is 354224848179261915075.
Recursive calls 9899
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes  edited but that is not exactly the main problem

Comment: Thanks  alot for correction and debugging this is the concept i was trying to impliment.

Comment: @FilsRato, no worries. Enjoy mitx

Answer (score -1):

when you define a function you specify the arguments and some of them could be optional only if you mark as them. in your case both arguments are not optional, so you have to invoke the method providing them.

checjing your code is obvious that the second arguments is a list. you also should check your algorithm, it's incomplete and may cause many errors, because you don't have stored in the "memory" list the elements "n-1" and "n-2"